# How to get subarray from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have `var ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and want some function `getSubarray(array, fromIndex, toIndex)`, that result of call `getSubarray(ar, 1, 3)` is new array `[2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Have you tried [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)?

Answer (score 580, accepted):

Take a look at [`Array.slice(begin, end)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
const ar  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// slice from 1..3 - add 1 as the end index is not included

const ar2 = ar.slice(1, 3 + 1);

console.log(ar2);
```

Comment: It's probably worth explicitly mentioning here that the original `ar` is unmodified.

`console.log(ar);`

`// -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: Also, don't make the mistake of confusing the `slice()` method with `splice()`: `splice()` changes the original array while `slice()` doesn't.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what if I try to slice using parameters, that'd raise some sort of "index out of bounds" error? In the example imagine I'd go with `ar.slice(4, 4);`? I guess I should try out :x..

Comment: @Igor No, slice does not raise an exception.  If the `end`  is greater than the length of the sequence, slice extracts through to the end of the sequence (`arr.length`). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: I want to add another note that `slice` does not raise exceptions for any type of input (string, undefined, object whatever). If `start` is out of range (negative or greater than the length), it just returns an empty array.

Answer (score 17):

For a simple use of `slice`, use my extension to Array Class:

```
Array.prototype.subarray = function(start, end) {
    if (!end) { end = -1; } 
    return this.slice(start, this.length + 1 - (end * -1));
};
```

Then:

```
var bigArr = ["a", "b", "c", "fd", "ze"];
```

**Test1**:

```
bigArr.subarray(1, -1);
```

< ["b", "c", "fd", "ze"]

**Test2:**

```
bigArr.subarray(2, -2);
```

< ["c", "fd"]

**Test3:**

```
bigArr.subarray(2);
```

< ["c", "fd","ze"]

Might be easier for developers coming from another language (i.e. Groovy).

Comment: [Don't modify objects you don't own](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/)

Comment: What K_7 said; most especially, monkey-patching the Builtins (Object, Array, Promise, etc) is *very* naughty. See the famous example of [MooTools forcing a rename](https://github.com/tc39/Array.prototype.includes/commit/4b6b9534582cb7991daea3980c26a34af0e76c6c) of the proposed native `Array.prototype.contains` to `Array.prototype.includes`.

Comment: Not to mention, your `subarray` method delivers unexpected results. `bigArr.slice(1,-1)` returns `['b','c','fd']`, which you would expect (the -1 knocks one element off the end of the new array). But `bigArr.subarray(1,-1)` returns the same as `bigArr.subarray(1)`, which is to say *everything* from position 1 to the end of `bigArr`. You're also forcing users to always give negative numbers as the `end` parameter. Any `end >= -1` gives the same result as when `end === undefined`. On the other hand, `bigArr.slice(1,3)` returns `['b','c']`, which again is expected.

Answer (score 7):

```js
const array_one = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55];
const start = 1;
const end = array_one.length - 1;
const array_2 = array_one.slice(start, end);
console.log(array_2);
```

Comment: it does not compile here the correction : var array_one = [11, 22, 33, 44,55];
var ar2 = array_one.slice(0, array_one.length-1);
console.log(ar2)

Answer (score 7):

> I have var ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and want some function
> getSubarray(array, fromIndex, toIndex), that result of call
> getSubarray(ar, 1, 3) is new array [2, 3, 4].

## Exact Solution

```
function getSubarray(array, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    return array.slice(fromIndex, toIndex+1);
}
```

### Let's Test the Solution

```
let ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
getSubarray(ar, 1, 3)

// result: [2,3,4]
```

### [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
> into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included)
> where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The
> original array will not be modified.

Basically, slice lets you select a **subarray** from an array.

**For example, let's take this array:**

`const animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];`

**Doing this:**

`console.log(animals.slice(2, 4));`

**Will give us this output:**

`// result: ["camel", "duck"]`

**Syntax:**

```
slice() // creates a shallow copy of the array
slice(start) // shows only starting point and returns all values after start index
slice(start, end) // slices from start index to end index
```

[See shallow copy reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy)

Answer (score 1):

The **question** is actually asking for a **New array**, so I believe a better solution would be to combine [Abdennour TOUMI's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18359274/5448626) with a clone function:

```js
function clone(obj) {
  if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
  const copy = obj.constructor();
  for (const attr in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
  }
  return copy;
}

// With the `clone()` function, you can now do the following:

Array.prototype.subarray = function(start, end) {
  if (!end) {
    end = this.length;
  } 
  const newArray = clone(this);
  return newArray.slice(start, end);
};

// Without a copy you will lose your original array.

// **Example:**

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(array.subarray(2)); // print the subarray [3, 4, 5, subarray: function]

console.log(array); // print the original array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, subarray: function]
```

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object]

Comment: I dont think that slice will change the original array.

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice` returns a copy already. `Array.prototype.splice` modifies the original array.

Comment: The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object. See [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-S/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Downvoted.

Comment: As others have said, `slice` already returns a shallow copy, making this `subarray` implementation unnecessary. But it's also worth mentioning you've monkey-patched a builtin object, which is a big no-no. See the comments on [Abdennour TOUMI's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18359274/2211532).