# Remove n-th elements from the end of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

and i want to remove for example the 4 last values so as my array becomes this:
array = [1,2,3,4]
I used array.splice(array.length - 4, 1) but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538519/how-to-get-subarray-from-array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the function `slice` as follow:

```
.slice(0, -4)
```

*This approach doesn't modify the original Array*

```js
//                                    +---- From 0 to the index = (length - 1) - 4,
//                                    |     in this case index 3.
//                                  vvvvv
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].slice(0, -4);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

*This approach modifies the original Array*

```js
var originalArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

//                     +---- Is optional, for your case will remove 
//                     |     the elements ahead from index 4.
//                     v
originalArr.splice(-4, 4);
console.log(originalArr);

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

originalArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
//                  +---- Omitting the second param.
//                  |     
//                  v
originalArr.splice(-4);
console.log(originalArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

## Docs

- [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 2):

Removing 4 elements from the end a list

```
var myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var removed = myList.splice(-myList.length-4, 4);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/etuf28bj/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a length property

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

a.length -= 4 // delete 4 items from the end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.splice(0,4)
```

will remove 0 elements from the array begin and 4 elements from array ends

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter` for removing element(it will not modify existing array)

```js
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
array1=array.filter((x,i)=>i<array.length-4);
console.log(array1);
```

Or you can use `splice`(it will change array itself)

```js
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
array.splice(-4);
console.log(array);
```