# I want sub array from an array by neglecting the last two of its indexes (With out looping)

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
data=[];
r=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
data.push(r.splice(7,1));
```

At the end I don't need the 8,9, I need

```
data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Comment: What if your array has only 2 items?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get subarray from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538519/how-to-get-subarray-from-array)

Answer (score 2):

You can just shallow copy with [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
r = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
data = r.slice(0,-2)
```

Example:

```js
var r = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var data = r.slice(0,-2);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Which still uses a loop (it's unavoidable), it's just buried in `slice`.

Comment: Internally, it uses loop but I think OP is referring to avoid using explicit loop.

Comment: Probably. But just flagged it up in case they thought magic was involved. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice`

```js
var r = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let data = r.slice(0, 7);
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way also, with `r.length - 2` it just shorten your array
`length` by 2 so here it is discarding last two elements.

```js
r = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
r.length = r.length - 2;
console.log(r);
```