# how to find particular element from array and remove all next elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find a particular element from an array and remove all next elements from that particular array.

below is my code:

```
var data1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h];

var data2 = c; // this is element, that i want to find from data1 and 
remove all next element i.e. d, e, f, g, h .
```

And I want output like: var res = [a,b,c];

Thanks,

Comment: Loop through array, look for your element, stop loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538519/how-to-get-subarray-from-array

Answer (score 1):

Use `splice()`. You need to get the index of `data2` value in `data1` and then use that index to remove all the elements after that in `data1`.

```js
var data1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];
var data2 = 'c';
data1.splice(data1.indexOf(data2)+1, data1.length);
console.log(data1);
```